# Getting ParseException: Unparseable date exception in Kotlin

Tags: android, date, kotlin, simpledateformat

I'm trying to display an incoming ISO Date like (2021-02-15T00:00:00.000Z) to a Textview in the following format: "dd MM yyyy".
But I get the following error when parsing the date.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:549)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
         Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950) 
         Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2021-02-15T00:00:00.000Z"
            at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:362)
```

Here is the **Kotlin** code:

```
val format = SimpleDateFormat(
    "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'",
    Locale.getDefault()
)
val initialConvertedDate = format.parse(customfield.value)

val simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat(
    "dd MM yyyy",
    Locale.getDefault()
)
val finalDate = simpleDateFormat.format(initialConvertedDate)

tv2.text = finalDate
```

Comment: Did you try to use predefined formatters? https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter#predefined-formatters

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. See if you either can use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) or add [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project, in order to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 3):

Use the pattern, `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX` where `X` truly represents the [timezone offset](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). In your date-time string, the timezone offset is `Z` which stands for Zulu and specifies UTC (timezone offset of `+00:00` hours).

The format that you have used has two problems:

1. It makes `Z` as a character literal and therefore it does not represent timezone offset.
2. It does not specify fraction-of-second i.e. `SSS`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException {
        String strDateTime = "2021-02-15T00:00:00.000Z";
        SimpleDateFormat sdfInput = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX", Locale.getDefault());
        Date date = sdfInput.parse(strDateTime);
        SimpleDateFormat sdfOutput = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy");
        sdfOutput.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));
        String formatted = sdfOutput.format(date);
        System.out.println(formatted);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
15 02 2021
```

Note that the legacy date-time API (`java.util` date-time types and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat`) is outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using it completely and switch to `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Demo using modern date-time API:**

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String strDateTime = "2021-02-15T00:00:00.000Z";
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(strDateTime);
        System.out.println(odt);

        DateTimeFormatter dtfOutput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MM yyyy");
        String formatted = dtfOutput.format(odt);
        System.out.println(formatted);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-02-15T00:00Z
15 02 2021
```

Note that the modern date-time API is based on [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and therefore you do not need to use a `DateTimeFormatter` explicitly in order to parse a date-time string that is already in the ISO-8601 format.

Learn more about the the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>